# It would be useful to have a local version of the site available to my office network as I am developing it, anyone know how to configure this?

Tags: windows-7, dns, intranet, iis-7

I develop on my machine and use my local IIS to test the site. I was thinking it would be really useful for showing people in the office a prototype or demo if I could just IM them a URL to this instance of the site that would be available on the local network in the office. Then they could browse to it instead of having to get up and come over here. Also it would allow them to test it in their browser as an extra perk.

Has anyone done this kind of thing, how would I configure it?

Comment: Am I missing something or does http://<yourip>/application not work? I understand your IP may be dynamic, but I'm guessing you can work around that?

Comment: @Tejaswi hmm, URL must be well formed, I'll give it a shot though to see if it at least almost works then I can get some local A-Records set up, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are just using your local IIS, you should be able to hand our your IP or machine name and others could access it. Give this a try and let us know if you have any errors doing so ... please note you might have to toy around with anonymous access permissions so just keep that in mind coming out of the gate.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Now I just need to get the local DNS working as the site requires well formed URLs.